# insert numeric values ​through TextEditingController? Dart

Tags: flutter, dart, model-view-controller

I'm trying to consume an API so I can create a new user.
I use the MVC pattern to create the models.

```
    class PostProduto{
          final String? name;
          final int? age;
          final String? image;
    }
```

I use the TextEditingController to store the name that is typed in the FieldText, but when applied to the numeric field it shows the following error: The argument type 'String' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'int?'.

```
class CreateUser extends StatefulWidget {...}

class _CreateUserState extends State<CreateUser> {

  late final TextEditingController _nameController;
  late final TextEditingController _ageController;

  
  final PrincipalRepositorioImplement _dioClient =
      PrincipalRepositorioImplement();

  bool isCreating = false;

  @override
  void initState() {
    _nameController = TextEditingController();
    _ageController = TextEditingController();

    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(),
        body: Container(
          child: Column(
            children: [

              TextField(
                controller: _nameController,
                decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter name'),
              ),

              TextField(
                controller: _ageController,
                inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                  FilteringTextInputFormatter.allow(RegExp(r'[0-9]')),
                ],
                decoration: InputDecoration(hintText: 'Enter Value Price'),
              ),
              
              SizedBox(height: 16.0),
              isCreating
                  ? CircularProgressIndicator()
                  : ElevatedButton(
                      onPressed: () async {
                        setState(() {
                          isCreating = true;
                        });


                        if (_nameController.text != '' && _valuePriceController.text != '') {
                          PostProduto postproduto = PostProduto(
                            name: _nameController.text,
                            age: _ageController.text,
                            
                          );


                          PostProduto? retrievedUser = await _dioClient
                              .createProduct(produto: postproduto);

                          if (retrievedUser != null) {
                            showDialog(
                              context: context,
                              builder: (context) => Dialog(
                                child: Container(...),
                                  child: Padding(
                                    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                                    child: Column(
                                      crossAxisAlignment:
                                          CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                                      children: [
                                        Text('ID: ${retrievedUser.id}'),
                                        Text('Name: ${retrievedUser.name}'),
                                        Text('age: ${retrievedUser.age}'),
                                      ],
                                    ),
                                  ),
                                ),
                              ),
                            );
                          }
                        }
                        setState(() {
                          isCreating = false;
                        });
                      },
                      child: Text(
                        'Create user',
                        style: TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0),
                      ),
                    ),
            ],
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

is there another controller to use for numeric values? I tried parse to int but it didn't work

Comment: How did you try to parse? It should work, consider using `int.tryParse` which will not throw but return null if the string can't be parsed as integer.

Comment: apparently it works, I applied the conversion method when sending to the API and it stopped alerting the error, thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

as the API expects a value of type int to receive, it is necessary to parse it when sending a request

This form uses the following structure:

```
                        if (_nameController.text != '' && _valuePriceController.text != '') {
                      PostProduto postproduto = PostProduto(
                        name: _nameController.text,
                        age: int.tryparse(_ageController.text),

                      );
```